# SEO - localized url - best pattern

Tags: seo, url

I want to support languages (fr,en,de).
My home page:

https://example.com/ (content localized based on webBrowser settings)

Language selection links available to set language in a cookie:

```
http://example.com/en 
http://example.com/fr
http://example.com/de
```

### Which pattern is the best for SEO?

### 1. eng. url + lang:

```
http://example.com/fr/buy
http://example.com/en/buy
http://example.com/de/buy
```

### 2. localized url + lang:

```
http://example.com/fr/acheter
http://example.com/en/buy
http://example.com/de/kaufen
```

### 3. localized url with no lang specified

```
http://example.com/acheter
http://example.com/buy
http://example.com/kaufen
```